# Calculating overlap of several lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, line, overlapping-features, vector-layer

I've traced several lines that represent people's paths. Some of these lines overlap several times. I would like to get a view showing for each segment of my lines the number of line overlaps.

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

The methods I have used until now are:

1. convert the lines into points (via Qchainge plug-in) and then create a heatmaps.
2. using a procedure that shows the result in vector format (but very long):

Starting from the original layer *"orig"*:

- From *"orig"* create a layer of segments called *"seg"* by using Explode lines (QGIS).
- From *"seg"* extract the center points of each segment, called *"centr"* using Point along lines with parameter 0.5 (QGIS).
- from *"centr"* delete duplicates, call *"centruniq"* using Delete duplicate geometries (QGIS)
- From *"centruniq"* create buffers of 50 cm called buff using Buffer (QGIS).
- Run Count points analysis in polygon (QGIS) with input *"buffer"* and *"centr"*, call output *"count"*.
- To *"seg"* element duplicates, call *"seguniq"* using Delete duplicate geometries (QGIS)
- Join attributes from location of *"seguniq"* with count call final using intersects: segment vector with total number of passages attribute (*"orig"* elements)
- style by category

I would like to ask if there was a faster solution that would allow me to display the number of line overlaps?

Comment: Perhaps these threads can help you [Line width and labels based on blended values of features sharing same geometry in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304379/line-width-and-labels-based-on-blended-values-of-features-sharing-same-geometry) and [Selecting features with same geometry in same shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304352/selecting-features-with-same-geometry-in-same-shapefile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may reduce the steps in the workflow.

(1) Explode lines (same as your first step)

(2) On the `Exploded` layer, `Count` the number of overlaps using an expression:

```
count('Explode', group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry))
```

---

Some use-cases will be:

(A) To set the line width:

[image]

(B) To use it for the label:

[image]

---

Input

[image]

Output

[image]