# Cleaning overlapping polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, overlapping-features

I have land use data as a polyline layer. Most of these polylines are overlapping at the common boundary. First of all, I want to clean them and get only one poly line feature, which does not overlap.I have tried to clean my polylines using `v.clean` in QGIS but it is not working.

Which Pug in in QGIS does this process or is there any way to do it?

ETGeowizards has a clean polyline function which does what I really want, Unfortunately i do not have the license for that software.

[image]

Comment: Please ask questions separately. I suggest you do some research on the first question, since it is rather common.

Comment: What were your inputs and tools in v.clean?  I'd start with a break and snap of lines with a suitable tolerance on the first run.  Then you could run it again using rmdupl although at that point I would use what Ash suggested in his answer and run the delete duplicate geometries tool.

Comment: v.clean--> input featur type:line, cleaning tool: break, snap, rmline thrshold:0,1,1

Comment: @ maiyourathaan  When v.clean runs keep an eye on the log; it should report on the number of duplicates in the result.  Did you try the remove duplicate geometries  tool after running the v.clean?

Comment: Are the overlapping lines identical or overlap in some places and not in other?

Comment: @BERA yes, it overlaps in some places, For example boundary lines does not have adjacent poly lines, therefore, it does not contain any overlapping lines, but all of the interior lines were overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to `Vector general | Delete duplicate geometries` tool and it works fine. good luck.

If you want a more elaborate way [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/304358/103942) might help you.

If you are interested in creating topology rules in QGIS please use the topology plugin and read [this article](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html). Using the topology plugin, you will define a rule to find all duplicates and remove them easily.

Comment: I am still having overlapping elements using this delete geometry tool

Comment: Use Topology Checker plugin. It's the only way then. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Have you succeeded in using the topology checker?

Comment: it is not working at all